# Creating Command Inside a Domain Event Handler In CQRS

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, domain-events

I have a simple scenario regarding CQRS and DDD in mind and I can't figure out the right way to implement it:

Order and Buyer are two aggregate roots inside Ordering service. When a user checks out the basket:

1. An **integration event** is raised in (basket) service.
2. It's handler inside Ordering service gets called.
3. Inside this handler, a CreateOrderCommand is created and dispatched.
4. The command handler instantiates an "Order".
5. As the result, a **domain event** is raised "OrderStartedDomainEvent".
6. Inside it's handler, the side effects regarding other aggregates (e.g. Buyer) must be applied: A Buyer is instantiated (if not exists already).

So, after this scenario, I want to change the order state. Changing order state requires a command. Where am I supposed to dispatch this command? From what I read so far, it's not appropriate to create and dispatch the command inside **domain event handler**.

Also, if I need to raise a domain event here, how can I do that? Since the Buyer constructor may not get called (if it already exists). So is it correct to raise a domain event inside a **domain event handler**?

I searched a lot but the previous answers were so complicated for me . I'd appreciate if someone clarifies. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you need is a saga. Here is 2 good articles: 1) https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/05/14/saga-patterns-wrap-up/, 2) https://blog.jonathanoliver.com/cqrs-sagas-with-event-sourcing-part-i-of-ii/

Comment: @MaximeGélinas Thanks for the good references you mentioned regarding saga. But in my case, saga won't help since these command are all in one bounded context/microservice and should be handled in as single process. So I believe there's no need for saga.

Comment: You're right. A saga is overkill if you're in a single process. Then a process manager might be the solution (i.e. a stateless saga). A process manager task is to listen for an event and send a command. (It's a fancy name for an event handler which send a command.)

Answer (score 1):

> From what I read so far, it's not appropriate to create and dispatch the command inside domain event handler.

You would probably dispatch the messages from the *application* event handler.  The domain model is pure in memory bookkeeping; the application layer/component is responsible for moving information from one place to another.

A way of thinking about this sort of design is that the application handler is orchestrating messages between a number of components, one of which happens to be the domain model.

Comment: Since application layer in my code is actually the command handlers, I don't think dispatching a command inside another command handler would be right?

Comment: "the application handler is orchestrating messages between a number of components". This is the definition of a saga.

Comment: Saga means something very different -- see Garcia-Molina and Salem 1987.  "Process Manager" - as described by Hohpe and Woolf in _Enterprise Integration Patterns_ is a closer match.